# Trigger a JavaScript function with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I want to trigger a client side function JavaScript, with Nodejs
I'm trying to get a response from the Nodejs to display data on my website

A program will send an API to my Nodejs Api example (htpp://localhost:3000/apiResponse) containing some data
I want to get the API data to my frontend

How can I do this, or is there another way to trigger a function  value when a API sends to me?

Comment: use `websocket` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser native `fetch` function to call your API:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/apiResponse')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

or

```
const main = async () => {
  const json = await (await fetch('http://localhost:3000/apiResponse')).json();
  console.log(json);
};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would handle it.

1. Create a function in your front-end that makes a request to your local node server. The function is asynchronous because we're not sure how long the server will take to respond. Then you could call the function inside of a button click, for example.

```
  const handleGetResponse = async () => {
    let data = {};
    try {
      const response = await fetch("htpp://localhost:3000/apiResponse").then(res => res.json())
        data = response;
        console.log("%cdata:", data);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

2. Create a function in your node file that handles the response

```
const nodeHandleResponse = () => { // handle response };
```

3. In the same node file, create a path to receive the front-end request, & call the node function that handles the response. Then, send the response to your front-end.

```
app.get("/apiResponse", async (req, res) => {
  nodeHandleResponse().then(response => res.send(response))
});
```

Note how the request url from the front-end is the same as the node `GET` path -> "apiResponse".